# Remove strings if found remove a part of the string in JS

Tags: javascript

I'm facing a problem.

I have this:

```
<input type="hidden" name="Boss" id="Boss" value="8,116,167,198,139,203,158,170,">
```

Actually I have this code in js:

```
// On click on element with class .Boss
$("form").on("click", ".Boss", function(event){
  var clickedId = $(this).attr('value')+','; // give me 8,
  var locationBtn = $('#Boss'); // Select the input
  var locationBtnValue = $('#Boss').val(); // Take the select value

  if(locationBtnValue.toString().indexOf(clickedId) == -1) { locationBtn.val(locationBtnValue + clickedId); }
  else { locationBtn.val(locationBtnValue.replace(clickedId,'')); }
});
```

My problem is: if want to decide to remove the `8` my javascript do not remove the item `8,` but the first occurrence it will find in my string, so 8,116,167,19**8,**139,203,158,170,. So it breaks my other item...

How can I make to do not break it ?

Thanks.

Comment: Your final outcome is not clear to me. What is the initial input and what is the final output?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to be consistent is by splitting it into an array and then removing the occurence.

```
// On click on element with class .Boss
$("form").on("click", ".Boss", function(event) {
  var clickedId = $(this).attr('value'); // give me 8
  var locationBtn = $('#Boss'); // Select the input
  var locationBtnValue = locationBtn.val(); // Take the select value
  var ids = locationBtnValue.split(','); //split into an array

  var index = ids.indexOf(clickedId); //index of clickedId inside ids

  if(index > -1) { //found
      ids = ids.splice(index, 1); //remove from ids

  } else {
      ids.push(clickedId); //add to ids
  }

  locationBtn.val(ids.join(','));      

});
```

Comment: Hello, thanks for your idea but if I click it gain, it do not keeps old datas. I have just the current clicked one.

Answer (score 1):

I do not know what your final outcome is, but I think you want it to be `116,167,198,139,203,158,170,` In this case you can split and filter the array to get rid of the value.

```
var str = "8,116,167,198,139,203,158,170,";  //the input
var updated = str.split(",")   //turn it into an array
                 .filter(function (val) { //loop through all the elements applying this function
                     return val!=="8"; //keep the item if the index does not match the item
                 }
              ).join(",");  //turn array back into a string
```

Answer (score 0):

That's what `replace` does when you pass it a string, it replaces the first occurrence.

You need to pass it a regular expression with the global modifier, like this

```
locationBtnValue.replace(/8,/g,'')
```

you can do the same thing with the RegExp constructor, and create a regular expression from the string you have

```
var clickedId = $(this).val() + ',';

var regex = new RegExp(clickedId, "g");

locationBtnValue.replace(regex,'');
```